# Is it possible to use non-ASCII characters in hyperref labels with htlatex?

Tags: hyperref, html

As I lay out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/htlatex-leaves-undefined-reference-link-but-pdflatex-produces-correct-outp/3192#3192) when using hypperef it appears to be problematic if anyone is using non-ASCII characters for hypertarget/hyperlink label names and then uses htlatex (with MikTeX on Windows) to produce HTML files.

Long story short is that using `\hypertarget{labelTwö}{Link Text Two}` (note non-ASCII `ö`) will simply not work with htlatex, but will work with pdfLaTeX.

Sub points for me here are:

- Is this expected?
- Why does it not work?
- Does it work under non MikTeX systems?
- Any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly expect troubles. \label expands commands in his argument. And Umlaute are commands if you use inputenc. As an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
abc\label{öä}
\end{document}
```

Without the T1-encoding in fontenc this wouldn't work in pdflatex, with T1 the definition of ö and ä is a bit more "label"-friendly. But if you look in the aux-file you see \newlabel{\"o\"a}{{1}{1}}. Chances that things like this breaks later are high.